# angularjs setting input variable via regular javascript

Tags: jquery, angularjs

If I set an input variable like

```
input.value = 'Something';
```

I know I can trigger an update to angularjs via

```
$(input).trigger('input');
```

Can I trigger the same event using regular Javascript? Without using jQuery?

Comment: Should be using models if you're using Angular, FYI (deleted answer, felt like more of a comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can do it. Try this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value = "Something";
```